# Real and Imaginary part of $e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you express the real and imaginary parts of $f(z) = e^z$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$? I know how to express it in terms of $x$ and $y$, but not in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: If you can express $e^z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ then it only remains to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ ...

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

> $$e^{r\cos\theta}\cos(r\sin\theta)+ie^{r\cos\theta}\sin(r\sin\theta).$$